# Dictionary Getting Overwritten in While Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
def get_list_expenses():
  expense_list = {}
  print('Please type the name of the expense followed by the price of the expense')
  while True:
    name = input('Name of expense: ')
    price = int(input('Price of expense: '))
    expense_list.update({
        'name': name,
        'price': price,
    })
    cont = input('Want to add another? [y/n] ').lower()
    if cont == 'n':
        break
 print(type(expense_list))
 print(expense_list)
 return expense_list

Input ==========================
Please type the name of the expense followed by the price of the expense
Name of expense: Food
Price of expense: 100
Want to add another? [y/n] y
Name of expense: Car Insurance
Price of expense: 200
Want to add another? [y/n] n

Output =========================
<class 'dict'>
{'name': 'car', 'price': 200}
```

I'm new to python and wanted to try and make a budget application to save me time manually inputting information to excel. My idea was to create a loop that would take in the name of an expense and the price per month of it. I wanted to put this into a `dictionary` so I could `.get` the information whenever I needed it. However, my dictionary keeps getting overwritten. I've tried a few different solutions I can find online but nothing worked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you want to be keeping a **list** of expenses (where each expense is a dictionary)

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want `expense_list` to be a list of name/price dicts, do you want `expense_list[name]` to be a list of prices associated with `name`, or a total sum associated with `name`?

Comment: Surely you meant to add an element to your dictionary with the `[]` operator :)

Comment: Please specify the desired output and/or usage so that we can provide useful suggestions and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the update method on a dictionary you are basically rewriting the dictionary from scratch at every iteration, for this reason you see a single value at the end (the last one).

I would suggest to create an empty list and then append a new dictionary of values at every iteration:

```
def get_list_expenses():
  expense_list = []
  print('Please type the name of the expense followed by the price of the expense')
  while True:
    name = input('Name of expense: ')
    price = int(input('Price of expense: '))
    expense_list.append({
        'name': name,
        'price': price,
    })
    cont = input('Want to add another? [y/n] ').lower()
    if cont == 'n':
        break
 print(type(expense_list))
 print(expense_list)
 return expense_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
expense_list.update({
    'name': name,
    'price': price,
})
```

Should be:

```
expense_list.update({name,price})
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is a key value pair. In your case key will be 'Name of expense' and value will be price. The way you are creating you have 2 keys in dictionary. 1st key is 'name' and second key is 'price'.

You can simply do:

```
expense_list[name] = price
```

If name exists it will update otherwise will add.

Comment: it doesn't solve OP problem; even if it's better than "update". OP wants a list of dicts, else no need for a loop

Comment: OP doesn't clearly states that he needs a list of dictionary. What purpose will it solve if he has a list and has to iterate to get desired value. From his statement I think he just need the price of the expense and quick lookup.  The while loop is to keep on adding the items & nothing else.

Comment: " However, my dictionary keeps getting overwritten": OP clearly doesn't have the proper data structure here

Answer (score 0):

Make `expense_list` an actual list:

```
expense_list = []
```

and then `append` to it

```
expense_list.append({
    'name': name,
    'price': price,
    })
```